# Как получить координаты полигона vl-interaction-draw? vuelayers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
                                    <vl-map data-projection="EPSG:4326" style="height: 400px">
                                        <vl-view :zoom.sync="zoom" :center.sync="center" :rotation.sync="rotation"></vl-view>

                                        <vl-layer-tile>
                                        <vl-source-osm></vl-source-osm>
                                        </vl-layer-tile>

                                        <vl-feature>
                                            <vl-geom-polygon :coordinates="formatedPolygon"></vl-geom-polygon>
                                        </vl-feature>

                                        <vl-layer-vector z-index="1">
                                            <vl-source-vector :features.sync="formatedPolygon" ident="the-source"></vl-source-vector>

                                            <vl-style-box>
                                                <vl-style-stroke color="green"></vl-style-stroke>
                                                <vl-style-fill color="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"></vl-style-fill>
                                            </vl-style-box>
                                        </vl-layer-vector>
                                        
                                        <vl-interaction-draw 
                                        @drawend="drawEnd"
                                        type="Polygon" source="the-source">
                                            <vl-style-box>
                                                <vl-style-stroke color="blue"></vl-style-stroke>
                                                <vl-style-fill color="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"></vl-style-fill>
                                            </vl-style-box>
                                        </vl-interaction-draw>
                                    </vl-map>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужна возможность получения координат после создания interaction ( vl-interaction-draw  )

Comment: @leha1 в документации упоминается event `drawend`. Ловите его и, скорее всего, в одном из параметров, с которым он выбрасывается, будет содержаться нужная вам информация.